# E824: Incompatible undo file when opening init.vim

Tags: neovim, startup

I get this error

> E824: Incompatible undo file: /root/.cache/nvim/undo/%root%.config%nvim%init.vim
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

when trying to open `init.vim`.

When then pressing ENTER it seems to work ok.

How do I get rid of the error message?

Comment: At some point neovim changed the undo-file format. And that makes older undo files incompatible. That's exactly what you see here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what was the origin of the problem, but clearing the `/undo` folder solved the issue.